# Importing python modules with Apache

Tags: python, apache, import, module

I am trying to get a python cgi script working on Apache 2.2.

I have `reporting.cgi` in cgi-bin and its working fine.

```
import sys
import os
import clr
import pypyodbc
import cgi.

# HTML Header
print '<html>'
print '<head>'
print '<link rel="stylesheet" href="../html_docs/epydoc.css" type="text/css" />'
print '<meta http-equiv="Content-Type"  content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />'
print '<title>Test Framework</title>'
print '</head>'
..
...
..
```

However, there's other Python modules I need to use on a network drive. (genutils.py)

So I try to import the location and import genutils.py.

```
sys.path.insert(0, 'I:/swd/Shared/Python')
import genutils
```

However, now when I try to call my webpage I get

```
[Mon Oct 07 14:02:25 2013] [error] [client 10.70.26.3]   File "C:/Program Files (x86)/Apache Software Foundation/Apache2.2/cgi-bin/reporting.cgi", line 23, in <module>\r\r
[Mon Oct 07 14:02:25 2013] [error] [client 10.70.26.3] ImportError: No module named genutils.
```

I've also `sys.path.append` and not using drive letters (`//machine/dir/swd/shared/python`)

Any advice is much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're running on Windows. Presuming Apache is running as a service, you will need to make sure that the account which Apache is running under can access the network resources it requires. A better practice, IMHO, is to deploy the complete software stack on the server where it's needed. That way you have less dependencies between servers.

Comment: True, I am on windows.

Comment: This looks like the reason. If I move the file I need to a local directory it works fine. So I can run locally (which is unlikely as as its a shared python file or provide a secure way or granting my Apache service network access (not very secure)